# Python Extremely Simple Calculator Literally adds the numbers

Tags: python

So I'm making a very simple calculator as my first real project in python on to which I will add more features but now the problem is that it adds numbers literally so if i type `2` as the first number and `3` as the second it will give `23`:
This is my code

```
a = input ('Enter the first number')
b = input ('Enter the second number')
c = (a+b)
print (c)
```

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 4):

`input` returns a string in py3.x, use `int()` to convert that string to an integer:

```
a = int(input ('Enter the first number'))
b = int(input ('Enter the second number'))
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2.7, input takes only numberical values. But in Python 3.x, input() returns a string. So you are literaaly concatenating two strings in your code. So, cast them to `int`

```
a = int(input ('Enter the first number'))
b = int(input ('Enter the second number'))
```

This converts the numbers to integers and then adds them

Comment: In py2.x `input` can take any value not just numerical values, only difference is it is equivalent  to `eval(raw_input)`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: `input()` in python 2.7 throws error if you enter any non numeric value

Comment: No, it does not. `input()` on Python 2.x accepts any valid Python expression, as stated clearly in the documentation. If you want to enter a string, put quotes around it. If you want to enter a list, put brackets around it. And so on.

Comment: That's because if you type a alphanumeric string in `input`, then it looks for a variable of that name, if that variable is not found it raises `NameError`. Pass the `repr` version of any object and it'll work fine.